# fade in then fade out after some time by using css-transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'd like to fade in, wait some time, then fade out an element of homepage using jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass`

This JS-code fades in the div but doesn't fade it out. I'm using jQuery 2.1.3

```
if ($("#save-success").hasClass("fadeout")){
     $("#save-success").removeClass("fadeout").addClass("fadein", function() {
         $(this).delay(2000).removeClass("fadein").addClass("fadeout");
    })
}
```

I've got this CSS:

```
.fadein, .fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

this HTML:

```
<div id="save-success" class="fadeout">
  Successfully saved
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`addclass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method doesn't take callback as argument. Try this instead:

```
if ($("#save-success").hasClass("fadeout")) {
  $("#save-success").removeClass("fadeout").addClass("fadein");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#save-success').removeClass("fadein").addClass("fadeout");
  }, 2000);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwugyo4v/

Answer (score 2):

You should change your CSS

```
.fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Without Classes**

```
if ($("#save-success").hasClass("fadeout")){
     $("#save-success").fadeIn(400,  function() {
         $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try the update **without classes** code.

Comment: Pure CSS-animations are smoother especially on mobile-phones